# E/Volley: [33049] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-volley

I am using `RecyclerView` to display data fetched from DB. It's not working.

> GETTING AN ERROR E/Volley: [33049] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404.

Need to parse below Response:-

> ```
> [
> {
> "code":"23232",
> "desc":"ddddjdkdkcn",
> "price":[
> "price"
> ]
> },
> {
> "code":"de33fd",
> "desc":"ddds",
> "price":[
> "price"
> ]
> }
> ]
> ```

```
  public class Background {
    String url = "http://192.168.0.103/android_fetch.php";
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Data> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Background(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public ArrayList<Data> getList() {
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        int count = 0;
                        while (count < response.length()) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(count);
                                Data data = new Data(jsonObject.getString("code"), jsonObject.getString("desc"), jsonObject.getString("price"));
                                arrayList.add(data);
                                count++;
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestque(jsonArrayRequest);
       return arrayList;
    }
}
```

Comment: what response getting from your URL ?? will you post ? and check your is working or not on postman.

Comment: [
    {
        "code": "23232",
        "desc": "ddddjdkdkcn",
        "price": [
            "price"
        ]
    },
    {
        "code": "de33fd",
        "desc": "ddds",
        "price": [
            "price"
        ]
    }
] this is the response. Its working on postman

Answer (score 0):

First check your request in Postman . There is some error at back-end `php` side. After that your parsing method is also wrong .

There is mistake in this line i think .

```
 Data data = new Data(jsonObject.getString("code"), jsonObject.getString("desc"), jsonObject.getString("price"));
```

here you try to get all as  `jsonObject` but last `price` is `JSONArray` .

Try this way .

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonresponse) {
   try {
        Log.i("get response", "get response" + jsonresponse);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonresponse.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject response = jsonresponse.getJSONObject(i);

            String code = response.getString("code");
            String desc = response.getString("desc");

            if (response.getJSONArray("price") != null && response.getJSONArray("price").length() > 0) {
                JSONArray priceArray = response.getJSONArray("price");
                final int numberOfItemsInResp = priceArray.length();
                for (int j = 0; j < numberOfItemsInResp; j++) {
                    String price = priceArray.getString(j);   
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Common.ProgressDialogDismiss();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }     
}
```